# How do I get a response from Git into my make?

Tags: windows, git, shell

I'm trying to get Git's hash for my code into make.  I'm using the following command to run Git from the shell command:

```
MODULE_HASH:=$(shell git describe --long --dirty --always)
```

The variable MODULE_HASH is blank after the line runs.  To find the problem, I added some debug lines to the make file:

```
$(info SHELL = $(SHELL))
$(info PATH = $(shell cd))
$(info version = $(shell git --version))
MODULE_HASH:=$(shell git describe --long --dirty --always)
$(info MODULE_HASH = $(MODULE_HASH))
```

The output for these lines are:

```
SHELL = cmd.exe
PATH = C:\Projects\WIFi_Module\wifi_module_wiced_sdk
version = 
MODULE_HASH =
```

This shows that the shell is executing cmd but git is either not executing or make is not getting the response from git.  If I open cmd and run the git command from the path, it works. I copied the shell line from another make file where it works. What am I doing wrong?

I checked the version of the make executable.  The output doesn't list a version so I copied the output below:

```
C:\Projects\WIFi_Module\wifi_module_wiced_sdk>make --version
GNU Make Development-Git-29cd1e9699d1101444920827b412191e0f92e1e1
Built for Windows32
Copyright (C) 1988-2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: At least `git --version` writes to stderr, and you catch stdout. Don't know about `git describe`, but this is something you can easily try out by yourself.

Comment: (to OP: this seems like it should Just Work.) @user1934428: `git --version 2>/dev/null` prints the version to stdout in my shell; is this some Windows madness?

Comment: @torek : Ah, right. Must have made some typo when checking this.

Comment: Try it with a sane shell. `cmd.exe` was bad even when it was written and has not aged well.